# Laravel error tries to use log before autoload

Tags: php, laravel

I have a project with Laravel 4.
I use an helper in `config/database.php`

I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class log does not exist' in /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:741
Stack trace:
#0 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(741): ReflectionClass->__construct('log')
#1 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(631): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('log', Array)
#2 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(674): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('log', Array)
#3 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(842): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Psr\\Log\\LoggerI...')
#4 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(805): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#5 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(776): Illuminate\Container\C in /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 741
```

I checked and the class name thats passed to make on `/var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(842)`
is `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface`.

I assume the log class gets called before it is loaded and thats why it breaks. 
If I remove the use of the helper in `config/database.php` all works, even if I simulate errors.

Is there a way to resolve it?
I need the Helper there.

Comment: Somewhere, you're trying to use `Log::`, but it might not be imported or namespaced properly. Look for instances of `Log`, and make sure `use Log;` is included at the top of the file, or use `\Log`.

Comment: @TimLewis I use aws-sdk-php  Ssm, I get a response and it breaks on `$result = $client->getParameter([
                        'Name' => $param,
                        'WithDecryption' => true
                ]);`